# Apply css to raw html in Twig

Tags: css, twig, less

In my `.twig` file I'm inserting a string with an `<a>` tag embedded into a `<p>`:

```
<p class="order-details__header--text">{{ orderNumberString|raw }}</p>
```

where `orderNumberString` is: `"Order #: <a href='#'>1569-0306-4761-9759</a>"`.

However, while I'm trying to make the `<a>` tag green, my css (using less) isn't getting applied:

```
.order-details__header--text {
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;

  a {
    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

I know that the css is working for the `<p>`, but for some reason its not getting applied to the `<a>`, probably because I'm passing it in as a raw string.

Do I have to manually inline the css into the `<a>` or is there a way to correctly have the css be applied?

Comment: Is it being overwritten by other classes? Are there multiple stylesheets being applied maybe? Have you inspected the element to see what classes are being called?

Comment: If link is actual is clickable then the problem is not located within `twig`, as `twig` is rendered serverside and changes nothing about browser behavior and css

Comment: Can you share the generated HTML of {{ orderNumberString|raw }} please.